# How to include category and exclude certain taxonomy in posts

Tags: wordpress

I need to fetch posts from "blog" category but they should not contain certain taxonomy "offers".

What I did was

```
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type'     => 'post',
                                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                                'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'cat'      => $category->term_id,
                                        'category__in'  => $category->term_id,
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'offers',
                                        'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                    ),
                                ),
                            );
```

But I can't seem to get the correct posts. Is theabove method wrong?

Comment: Try with `operator' => 'NOT IN`

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this way but i am not sure this will work:

```
$args = array(
          'post_type'     => 'post',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'tax_query'     => array(
                               'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                        'fields'    =>  'term_id',
                                        'terms'     =>  $category->term_id,
                                     ),
                                     array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'offers',
                                        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                                     ),
                              ),
           );
```